# Multiple layouts with Handlebars and ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, template-engine, handlebars.js

If I'm using Handlebars as my templating engine with Express 4, it seems like there is only the option to specify a single layout template to use for all your views:

```
app.engine('hbs', expressHbs({extname:'hbs', defaultLayout:'layout.hbs'}));
```

What if your app needs multiple layouts? What if `viewA.hbs` uses one layout and `viewB.hbs` needs a different layout?

As I'm learning nodejs, I'm coming from a PHP Laravel background where the [Blade templating engine](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#blade-templating) has you specify which layout to use at the top of each view file. It makes it really simple to switch between layout templates for any given view.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You should be able to pass in the layout from your route/controller when you call the render method.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {layout: 'viewBLayout.hbs'});
});
```

I am pretty sure jade will let you switch layouts from inside the template but I don't know if you can do that with handlebars.

Answer (score 4):

If you use [express-hbs](https://github.com/barc/express-hbs#layouts), you can specify a layout in the template with a comment like:

```
{{!< layout}}
```

Alternatively, you can try [exphbs](https://github.com/gnowoel/exphbs/blob/master/docs/layouts.md#layout-comment). It also supports layout comments and multiple layouts can be nested. (Disclaimer: I wrote it.)

Comment: Thanks. Side-question: how come there are so many different implementations of express handlebars? express-hbs, exphbs, expressHbs, etc?

Comment: Glad you asked. I don't think I'm qualified to answer this question. But from my own experience, a vibrant community is usually a good thing. :)

Comment: The only downside about this is that project A has great idea #1 implemented and project B has great idea #2 implemented. You can't have both and it would have been better if people would have just collaborated on a single project that has both great ideas in it.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you first make two files named "main.handlebars" and "backend.handlebars" in /layouts directory:

Try this code for two routes if you want for example

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {layout: 'main'});
});

router.get('/backend', function(req, res) {
    res.render('home', {layout: 'backend'});
});
```